# Changing the Accent Color in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to set the active background color of the elements like button while clicking irrespective of the phone's current accent color?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice library for that in NuGet called **Windows Phone Theme Manager**. Type "theme manager" in the search box of NuGet manager window and you will find it.

Then all you have to do is add one line of code in **App.xaml.cs** file at the end of the constructor:

```
ThemeManager.SetAccentColor(AccentColor.Blue);
```

*Blue* is just an example. You can use any color.